# Why is Retrofit responding with 404 error code?

Tags: android, retrofit

I have written a Retrofit code which has a Yii2 backend. The problem is: when I call the web-service on backend, it works perfectly. However, when I try to call the web-service from android device; it throws a response code of 404. Here is what I have done:

I am targeting a url which looks like: http://192.168.0.104/root-web/web/index.php?r= and it had an end-point: root/register

```
public interface RegisterAPIService {
    @POST("practice/register")
    Call<RegisterModel> registerUser(@Body RegisterDetails registerDetails);
}
```

The code in my activity looks like this..

```
            RegisterDetails registerDetails = new RegisterDetails(email, mobile, password);

            RegisterAPIService registerAPIService = retrofit.create(RegisterAPIService.class);

            Call<RegisterModel> call =registerAPIService.registerUser(registerDetails);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<RegisterModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response<RegisterModel> response) {

                    Log.d("Message", "code..."+response.code() + " message..." + response.message()+" body..."+response.body());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

                }
            });
        } else {
             // Error
        }
    }
```

I am getting 404 for the above code. I am trying to send my parameters in the form of a POST request. Please guide me through it.

Comment: it means `page not found`. url you are passing is wrong. please check.

Comment: @Tauqir I am sending the same request from the web as well as iOS. It works. However, from android.. it gives this error.

Comment: are you using `emulator` or device. copy paste the url in browser and check.

Comment: @Tauqir I am using my device to debug.

Comment: @Tauqir Yes it shows me the Yii web page. And gives me correct error on my POST request.

Comment: what is the url you're passing in web browser?

Comment: FYI.. I have developed my web-service in Yii2. I am passing my machine's IP address. The one mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should call your development machine from the device, by its ip address, based on how they are connected. Also you can use Android Reverse Tethering tools for your operating system. for further study and options you can take a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)

Comment: can you call the url , from the web browser of your android device, successfully ?

Comment: I think you are missing the port number. On what port is your web service available for external client ? if you've not configured it, it may be 80, or 8080

Comment: It is showing on the android device's browser correctly. The error response. The default port is being used is 80

Comment: Is it due to the wrong Yii url format that I have..?

Comment: I'm thinking of the same...paste the exact url that you call from the browser once more

Comment: The base url that I have is http://192.168.0.104/root-web/web/index.php?r=

And the endpoint I have is like:
@POST("practice/register")

Should I combine them as base url and keep my endpoint as empty..?